# Is there a way to get $PWD in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

The SAM cli (and other remote/sibling docker setups I think, the SAM option in question -> `docker-volume-basedir`) need the absolute host path of the mount. I'd like there to be a platform agnostic method, using docker on multiple hosts (windows as well).

I understand that something like this wouldn't normally be available within the container.

I'm just baking a cygpath in .env atm.

Comment: Yes from https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/. I have tried few examples with ${PWD}, works fine in my git-bash.

Comment: You don't get compose errors that it's unset?

Comment: No, I didn't get the error. I am on Windows 10 with git-bash. It works fine for me. Can you try echo ${PWD} from your bash?